# Having trouble with writing HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying to write an HTML email and I've looked for countless tutorials online and can't seem to have them work. I'm writing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>



<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <tr>

   <td>

    Hello! how is everything

   </td>

  </tr>

 </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Which should display the html in the email but it's not. I'm using outlook.com to generate the html e-mail. is there a setting I need to use to write an html email or am I using the wrong code? any ideas? thanks!

I know I can view html e-mails because I receive emails from mailChimp and they render fine.

Comment: I believe all you need is the body. Don't need `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: *Exactly* how are you creating the HTML email? Outlook.com nor desktop Outlook let you manually set the HTML content of emails.

Comment: @Dai You can, but you have to paste in the rendered html from a browser

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out this page? It says there are some settings that need to be configured before sending the email.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-the-message-format-to-html-rich-text-or-plain-text-HP001232996.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be sending html email from Outlook, but here is how to have the html render:

View your code rendered in a web browser and `ctrl+a` select it all. Copy and paste that into the email body.

This is not good practice, but it will get the job done. If you are sending bulk emails you should check out a ESP like Campaign Monitor, Mailchimp or Constant Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Here's header information that works for me, if you want to give it a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
<title>Email Title</title>
</head>
<body>
asdf
</body>
</html>
```